# how to know the file names that pd.read_parquet is using when partition filter is passed?

Tags: python, pandas, file, metadata

I am reading as Pandas Dataframe some partitioned parquet files that satisfy a specific filter, using pd.read_parquet with pyarrow engine:

```
df_historic = pd.read_parquet(saving_path, filters=[
  ("location", "==", "London"), ("year", ">=",  2022), ("month", ">=", 6)
])
```

The problem is that I need to know the name of the partitioned files that pandas is using to create the dataframe as I need to delete them but keep the ones that not satisfy that filter.

I am trying to do an upsert of the parquet files, filtering them according the previous filter and making some transformations.

Anyone know a way where I can get that files' metadata? I suppose that there must be a way to know the files that are behind that pandas filter.

I would like to obtain the following:

```
df_historic = pd.read_parquet(saving_path, filters=[
  ("location", "==", "London"), ("year", ">=",  2022), ("month", ">=", 6)
])

**df_historic.METADATA_FILES = [
".\location=london\year=2023\month=6\6b48025316db48c197624f5ff7de2d48-0.parquet",
".\location=london\year=2023\month=7\6b48025316db48c197624f5ff7de2d58-0.parquet",
".\location=london\year=2024\month=2\6b48025316db48c197624f5ff7de2d68-0.parquet",
".\location=london\year=2024\month=3\6b48025316db48c197624f5ff7de2d78-0.parquet"...
]**
```

Thank you in advance!